# how to grab internal index of current loop in python when iter a list?

Tags: python, loops, indexing, counter

i got a `listx =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

i want to alter every Nth item of the list. For example i want to modify for every 2 item step, let say i want to modify by +1 .
so i want to get result = `[1+1,2,3+1,4,5+1,6,7+1,8,9+1] =[2,2,4,4,6,6,8,8,9]`

i can do this by using for-loop , by adding counter variable , then check the counter by counter%2==0. But this time i 'm just curious using single line statement. Here what i want =

`newlistx=[i+1 for i in listx]` <- this will modify all items, so i'm expecting i can use some internal indexing use in this iteration process, become like this :

`newlistx=[i+1 if (__indexing__%step==0) else i for i in listx]` where step=2.

Actually, i can use list.index() function , like this :

`newlistx=[i+1 if listx.index(i)%2==0 else i for i in listx]`

the problem this me thod only works if all the item is unique, if i got items which have same value then index() will return wrong value.

Again, i'm just curious if i can grab some internal indexing or counter , if exist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `enumerate` function.

```
newlist = [x + 1 if n % step == 0 else x
           for (n, x) in enumerate(oldlist)]
```

The `enumerate` function iterates over a sequence and yields the objects with their indexes.

Comment: Your use of `n` for the index and `i` for the list item makes me cringe.

Comment: @Markus: Indeed, I never would have written code like that on my own.  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = [n + 1 if i & 1 else n for i, n in enumerate(listx)]
```